# Is there any parallel HTML parser existing or in design?

Tags: html, parallel-processing, html-parsing

As I know, HTML parsing is difficult to parallelize due to its strong dependences.

Is there any parallel HTML parser existing or in design, so that a single HTML document can be parsed in parallel and a single DOM tree would be produced finally?

It could be either for earlier HTML versions, or the latest HTML5.

Comment: Why would you need to parse HTML in parallel?

Comment: Written in which language? And on which platform?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I don't have any requirements on the implementation details.

Comment: @WaleedKhan I am interested in how an HTML parser can be parallelized.

Comment: What do you mean by "Parallel"?   One thread per HTML file? One thread per *rendered* page? Multiple threads for a single document?  One thread for part of a document?

Comment: @IraBaxter Good comment. I mean multiple threads for a single document.

Comment: @JackWM But how would the parser know how to portion the HTML string?

Comment: @Šime Vidas IMO, that is implied as part of the question.

Comment: "Closed as not a real question"?   I think this is unreasonable. The question is real, has a straightfoward interpretation, is not any of the things claimed in the closed remark, and even several practical answers.  I think SO people are jumping the gun on closing questions, perhaps because they don't understand it or don't believe it has an answer.  "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy. "

Answer (score 3):

The "strong dependencies" in HTML aren't much different from a parsing point of view, than strong dependencies in any other language you might parse.  The real issue is that parsing one part of the file, usually depends on the left context.  The problem for a parallel parser is how to get left context?

There's [general theory](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.389&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about how to build parallel parsers, by breaking the text into chunks, parsing them separately, and stitching the parts together.  McKeeman's paper (referenced) claimed .85N speedup for N processors.

I seem to remember a paper that proposed to parse a file from both ends, meeting in the middle.  The right-going parser generated left context; the left-going parser generated right context.  You can do the bi-directional scanning relatively easily by *reversing* the grammar, and feed the forward and backward grammars to parser generators.   Gluing it together likely requires the kinds of techniques sketched in referenced paper.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has a GLR parser that uses *pipelining* to separate the lexing stages from parsing, and has a full HTML4 parser available.  (DMS is built on parallel foundations; it is relatively easy to configure it to parse individual files in parallel, too.)  That HTML4 parser is likely extendable to HTML5 using DMS's support for language dialects.

As a general rule, if you are only parsing one program (or HTML) file, this kind of parallelism really doesn't matter much, as it won't affect your overall performance much.  Most parsers are pretty fast and their time is largely covered by the effort to process the individual characters.  You'd probably get much of the speedup by breaking the file into chunks, and *lexing* the chunks individually, especially since much of HTML files is wasted whitespace.

If you had to process *lots* of HTML files, you'd probably be better off with one thread per file being parsed.  Then you can use pretty conventional parser technology in each thread.